# Business User Easy method to transfer file through SFTP Across Globe

Tags: ssis, sftp, ssis-2012

I have 800 business user across globe having limited coding skill.

There is an ETL Package developed to process file from specific folder.

```
Problem:- What could be the easiest way for business user to send file via SFTP.
```

Solution I proposed was rejected because they are not comfortable with it.

**Solution: WinSCP to use SFTP protocol and script component in SSIS package**

Please help.

Comment: There are many companies out there providing secure file sharing services. There's even ubiquitous and simple solutions like Dropbox. Or develop your own. For unskilled people, it's generally best to provide them a browser-based solution that offers a familiar interface without requiring any software installation.

Comment: @paddy: Thank You so much. can you please suggest any such browser based solution. The other concern was it should allign with company policy. what I approach I should take, if I need to develop own. Please suggest.

Comment: It sounds more like your question has to do with how to motivate a solution to business and less with how to use SSIS Scripts and WinSCP. Have you had a look at any of the guides on the internet on how to use WinSCP and SSIS? Can you show us your attempt?